# Does not direct to page in Microsoft Edge due to selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to parse remote response: Unknown error

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, microsoft-edge

I initiated web driver and try to connect a URL and it returns an exception 
What happens is: Open the web browser but does not direct to given Url and print error on the console log.

**My code is below**:

```
Webdriver driver  = new EdgeDriver();
driver.get("https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/welcome-to-docs");
```

**Error log**:

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to parse remote response: Unknown error

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:115)

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)

at  org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)

---

I enabled developer mode

I already installed WebDriver using below command in (C:\WINDOWS\system32>):
DISM.exe /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft.WebDriver~~~~0.0.1.0

I use the below versions:

- selenium version: '3.141.59'
- Browser: Microsoft Edge, Version 80.0.361.50 (Official Build)
  (64-bit)
- os build: 18362.535
- Windows Edition: 10 version 1903

**Any Idea on this?**

Answer (score 0):

> DISM.exe /Online /Add-Capability
>   /CapabilityName:Microsoft.WebDriver~~~~0.0.1.0

Using the above command will install the Microsoft WebDriver for Microsoft Edge Legacy versions 18, it is not available for the Microsoft Edge Version 80.0.361.50 (Official Build) (64-bit).

You could download the related Microsoft Edge WebDriver from [Here](https://msedgewebdriverstorage.z22.web.core.windows.net/), based on the Edge version number to download the WebDriver.

**Edit:**

Try to use the EdgeOptions to set the webdriver path, code as below:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;

        // EdgeOptions() requires using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge
        // Construct EdgeOptions with is_legacy = false
        EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions(false);
        edgeOptions.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge Beta\Application\msedge.exe"; 
        var msedgedriverDir = @"<download webdriver folder such as:D:\MicrosoftEdgeDriver\edgedriver_win64>";
        var msedgedriverExe = @"msedgedriver.exe";

        // Construct EdgeDriverService with is_legacy = false too
        var service = EdgeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(msedgedriverDir, msedgedriverExe, false);
        service.EnableVerboseLogging = true;

        var driver = new EdgeDriver(service, edgeOptions);

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://bing.com");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        driver.Close();
```

More detail information about using Chromium version Edge WebDriver, please check this link:

[WebDriver (Chromium)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium)

Comment: Seems still web driver not released to this version:
Browser: Microsoft Edge, Version 80.0.361.50 (Official Build) (64-bit)
os build: 18362.535

Comment: Perhaps it still using the original WebDriver, you could check above edit code, and use EdgeOptions to set the download webdriver path and edge path, then, create a EdgeDdriver object.